# Text following section name on same line (scrartcl) with section numbers in margin

Tags: formatting, koma-script, scrartcl

I would like to have text on the same line as my subsubsections (only) using KOMA scrartcl, AND have my section numbers in the margin. For example:

**1.1.1 Subsubsection Heading**   Some text that follows

I can achieve it by using the following:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
afterskip=-10pt%
]{subsubsection}
```

But there is a conflict with having numbers in the margin as well. I am using the following code to place the section numbers in the margin of the page, but using the redeclare will no longer place the number in the margin.

```
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
\makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's compatible with koma classes, but you could try titlesec package to achieve that. I don't have a LaTeX distro handy on this machine, thus I can't test right now, sorry.

Comment: @thymaro Do not use package `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: @esdd just like I suspected. Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\sectionlinesformat` is used by free-standing headings. Run-in headings use `\sectioncatchphraseformat`. So you have to redefine this command, too.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{% used by free-standing headings with style=section
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}
\renewcommand\sectioncatchphraseformat[4]{% used by run-in headings with style=section
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterskip=-1em%
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or alternatively:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{% used by free-standing headings with style=section
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}
\renewcommand\sectioncatchphraseformat[4]{% used by run-in headings with style=section
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}#4%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterskip=1em,% note the positive value
  runin=true% needs KOMA-Script version 3.26b or newer 
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you kindly.